# Changing Scenes in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am a beginner when it comes to SpriteKit, and I am trying to learn how to make a Pong Game. I am following a lot of tutorials, and now am trying to venture off and explore what I can do on my own.

I have a Pong game that works, however now I am trying to add a start menu to the game. Seems simple, but of course, I am getting an error.

I have a first screen that has the code that detects touch, and calls a method for each button...

[First Screen Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzwup.png)

All of that works... but when I click one of the buttons, the app crashes, and the debugger prints "Could not cast value of type 'PongTwo.GameScene' to 'SKSpriteNode'

[Debugger Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDqoL.png)

For instance, when I click on the button to pull up my GameScene... the error is located here:

[GameSceneError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxPQd.png)

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the error is telling you what the problem is.
You're casting the child node of the scene with the name `PlayingField`to a SKSpriteNode but it's not compatible with that type as it's a PongTwo.GameScene

**You might have two nodes in the node tree with the name `PlayingField`** but you haven't shown us enough of the code to see that.

Comment: You were right the first time! I had "PongTwo.GameScene in the PlayingField custom class. Thank you so much!